# Apache and PHP set up on M1 MacBook

Tags: php, apache, apple-m1

I apologize for the lengthy question, I am just trying to get all the information out here in case it is helpful in getting an answer. This is my first time setting up Apache and PHP. I am using an Apple Silicon MacBook.

I am trying to follow this tutorial called "[macOS 11.0 Big Sur Apache Setup: Multiple PHP Versions](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-bigsur-apache-multiple-php-versions)".

So far so good, but now I am at this part where I have to install a PHP Switcher Script.

> PHP Switcher Script
> We hard-coded Apache to use PHP 5.6, but we really
> want to be able to switch between versions. Luckily, some industrious
> individuals have already done the hard work for us and written a very
> handy little PHP switcher script.

[This is the piece of code](https://gist.github.com/rhukster/f4c04f1bf59e0b74e335ee5d186a98e2) I installed to get the sphp function I need.

What's supposed to happen is, if I type `sphp 5.6` into my Terminal, my PHP version should change to said version, in this case PHP@5.6. I even made appropriate changes in the httpd.conf and the sphp file to change the usr/local to opt/homebrew locations.

What happens now is after typing the sphp command, my terminal returns this, meaning it "works", but it doesn't.

```html
francisgomez@192 ~ % sphp 5.6
Switching to php@5.6
Switching your shell
Unlinking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@5.6/5.6.40... 25 symlinks removed.
Unlinking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.0/7.0.33... 0 symlinks removed.
Unlinking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.33... 0 symlinks removed.
Unlinking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.34... 0 symlinks removed.
Unlinking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.3/7.3.27... 0 symlinks removed.
Unlinking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.16... 0 symlinks removed.
Unlinking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.3... 0 symlinks removed.
Linking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@5.6/5.6.40... 25 symlinks created.

If you need to have this software first in your PATH instead consider running:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/php@5.6/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/php@5.6/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
Switching your apache conf
Restarting apache
Stopping `httpd`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `httpd` (label: homebrew.mxcl.httpd)
==> Successfully started `httpd` (label: homebrew.mxcl.httpd)

PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Feb 28 2021 06:37:47) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

All done!
```

It works in the sense that the sphp command does something, but it doesn't actually change the PHP version that is being used.

I think this has something to do with the `$apache_conf_path` in the sphp file? As I said, I already changed it from usr/local to opt/homebrew, but for some reason when I type `brew services`, the change doesn't happen. I am still stuck on the same PHP version I had earlier.

```html
francisgomez@192 ~ % brew services
Name              Status  User         Plist
httpd             started francisgomez /Users/francisgomez/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist
mongodb-community started francisgomez /Users/francisgomez/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
php               started francisgomez /Users/francisgomez/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
php@5.6           stopped              
php@7.0           stopped              
php@7.1           stopped              
php@7.2           stopped              
php@7.3           stopped              
php@7.4           stopped
```

The `php` indicated refers to PHP@8.0. It didn't change to PHP@5.6.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question in the comment section of the repository here: https://gist.github.com/rhukster/f4c04f1bf59e0b74e335ee5d186a98e2

Comment from: thomasisberg

> Hi! Works great! But I had to change this line: sudo sed -i.bak
> "/$native_osx_php_apache_module/a\ since Homebrew's Apache installed
> without a php module in the conf. (And if it did, it probably wouldn't
> be located at libexec/apache2/). Instead I used: sudo sed -i.bak
> "/LoadModule rewrite_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so/a\

Answer (score 0):

On MacBook M1 apache and PHP 7.3 is pre-installed. All i do was modify httpd.conf and uncommented `LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so` . I think changing this line for other PHP versions may help as well.